# Capitalise every word in String with extension function

Tags: string, function, kotlin, extension-function

I want to make a extension function in Kotlin, that converts the first letter of each word of the string to upper case

```
the quick brown fox
```

to

```
The Quick Brown Fox
```

I tried using the `capitalize()` method. That only though capitalised the first letter of the `String`.

Comment: So, where are you stuck?

Comment: i am using .capitalized() method but by using this method it effects only "The" but i am trying to did it in all sentence

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Since you know `capitalize()` all you need is to split the string with space as a delimeter to extract each word and apply `capitalize()` to each word. Then rejoin all the words.

```
fun String.capitalizeWords(): String = split(" ").map { it.capitalize() }.joinToString(" ")
```

use it:

```
val s = "the quick brown fox"
println(s.capitalizeWords())
```

will print:

```
The Quick Brown Fox
```

Note: this extension does not take in account other chars in the word which may or may not be capitalized but this does:

```
fun String.capitalizeWords(): String = split(" ").map { it.toLowerCase().capitalize() }.joinToString(" ")
```

or shorter:

```
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
fun String.capitalizeWords(): String =
    split(" ").joinToString(" ") { it.toLowerCase().capitalize() }
```

Comment: @SamuelKodytek I approved dropping `it` although I like it being there as I like `this` being there although it's useless too.

Comment: cheers! I understand your point, though I think, if you are already using the arrow notation, you should specify the name of the variable, for example: `word -> //More code`

Comment: @SamuelKodytek that would make it more readable but as I said I like `it` and `this`

Comment: I understand :)

Comment: `map` can be simplified by merging with `joinToString`. Like, `split(" ").joinToString(" ") { it.capitalize() }`

Comment: Note, that `String.capitalize()` is *deprecated* now and you should use `replaceFirstChar` instead

Answer (score 24):

It can be done in a simpler way than the accepted answer offers, check this:

```
fun String.capitalizeWords(): String = split(" ").joinToString(" ") { it.capitalize() }
```

Answer (score 10):

capitalise() is now deprecated and kotlin suggests to use replaceFirstChar instead

```kotlin
fun camelCase(string: String, delimiter: String = " ", separator: String = " "): String {
    return string.split(delimiter).joinToString(separator = separator) {
        it.lowercase().replaceFirstChar { char -> char.titlecase() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Why not use an extension property instead?

```kotlin
val String.capitalizeWords
    get() = this.toLowerCase().split(" ").joinToString(" ") { it.capitalize() }
```

Which can be called like:

```kotlin
val test = "THIS iS a TeST."
println(test.capitalizeWords)
```

Which would display:

```
This Is A Test.
```

Personally I think properties should be used for returns with no parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Latest elegant solution without any deprecated constuctions

```
fun String.toCamelCase(delimiter: String = " "): String {
    return split(delimiter).joinToString(delimiter) { word ->
        word.replaceFirstChar(Char::titlecaseChar)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`String#capitalize()` is deprecated.
use this instead:

```
query.replaceFirstChar { if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault()) else it.toString() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without deprecated methods:

```kotlin
fun String.capitalizeWords(): String =
    split(" ").joinToString(" ") { w -> w.replaceFirstChar { c ->  c.uppercaseChar() } }
```

Answer (score 0):

New way to capitalize the first character of string word.
As capitalize() is deprecated now following is the way to achieve this in kotlin.

```
        val string="the quick brown fox"

        val result= string.split(" ").joinToString(" ") {
            it.replaceFirstChar {it1 ->
                it1.uppercase()
            }
        }
        println("Result::$result")
```

upper block of code prints:

```
The Quick Brown Fox
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach will capitalise every word regardless of separators;

**Extension Function**

```kotlin
fun String.capitaliseEachWord(): String {
    val regex = "(\\b[a-z](?!\\s))".toRegex()
    return this.replace(regex) { it.value.uppercase() }
}
```

**Usage**

```kotlin
val input = "capitalise the/words*in&this    string"
val output = input.capitaliseEachWord()
print(output)
```

**Result**

```
Capitalise The/Words*In&This    String
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way you could do this with a transform:

```
fun String.capitalizeWords() = split(' ').joinToString(" ", transform = String::capitalize)
```

And a test for it:

```
class StringExtensionTest {
  @Test
  fun `test capitalize a sentance`() = run {
    Assert.assertEquals("Abba Sill Med Extra", "abba sill med extra".capitalizeWords())
  }
}
```

Comment: 'capitalize(): String' is deprecated. Use replaceFirstChar instead.