# How to capitalise first letters of all word in a sentence in Kotlin

Tags: android, string, kotlin

this is my/his house - Input

This Is My/His House - Output

In Swift ,there is capitalized method which gives the above output ,is there any way to achieve the same in kotlin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capitalise every word in String with extension function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042903/capitalise-every-word-in-string-with-extension-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Kotlin**

```
val s = "this is my/his house"
println(s.toCapitalizeEachWord())
```

**Extension Function:**

```
fun String.toCapitalizeEachWord() : String{
return this.split(" ").map {
    if(it.contains("/")){
        it.split("/").map { word -> word.replaceFirstChar { firstChar -> firstChar.uppercase() }
        }.joinToString("/")
    }else{
        it.replaceFirstChar { firstChar -> firstChar.uppercase() }
    }
}.joinToString(" ") }
```

**Input:** this is my/his house

**Output:** This Is My/His House

Comment: Thanks ,but if your compare the input & output
my/his
My/His
the above funtion doesn't work for this words

Comment: Answer updated, try now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to capitalize every word.

However `String.capitalize()` is now deprecated.

The easer solution is:

```
    fun String.capitalizeSentence(): String =
        this.trim().split("\\s+".toRegex())
            .joinToString(" ") { it.replaceFirstChar { if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.ROOT) else it.toString() } }
```

Comment: Thanks,but the word "my/his" needs to be converted to "My/His" ,but the method only converts as My/his

Answer (score 1):

My approach will capitalise every word regardless of separators;

**Extension Function**

```kotlin
fun String.capitaliseEachWord(): String {
    val regex = "(\\b[a-z](?!\\s))".toRegex()
    return this.replace(regex) { it.value.uppercase() }
}
```

**Usage**

```kotlin
val input = "capitalise the/words*in&this    string"
val output = input.capitaliseEachWord()
print(output)
```

**Result**

```
Capitalise The/Words*In&This    String
```

Answer (score 0):

Well many has posted correct core logic or main logic so you just needed to add little bit your own logic to work . Anyways below method is tested with your requirement and it is working fine

```
fun String.capitalizeEachWord() : String{
    return this.split(" ").map {
        if(it.contains("/")){
            it.split("/").map { word -> word.replaceFirstChar { firstChar -> firstChar.uppercase() }
             }.joinToString("/")
        }else{
            it.replaceFirstChar { firstChar -> firstChar.uppercase() }
        }
    }.joinToString(" ")
}
```